# 'router-outlet' not working without a 'routerLink' on the main template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I've just created a new angular project using the **Angular CLI** and scaffolded a new route **user** in it using the following commands.

```
ng new myproj
cd myproj 
ng g route user
```

And then I ran the **Angular CLI** server using `ng serve`.

But I can't see the content of the login template when I access the page `/login` unless I add a link to some route, i.e:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user']">User Info</a>
```

When I add the line above, then the `router-outlet` gets filled, but if I strip out this line, then the `router-outlet` renders empty again.

What's happening here?

**Does someone know why is this happening?**

### Example files

#### /src/app/myproj.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'myproj-app',
  templateUrl: 'myproj.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['myproj.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/user', component: UserComponent}
])
export class MyprojAppComponent {
  title = 'Main Component working!';
}
```

#### /src/app/myproj.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the non-understandable workaround

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user']">User Info</a>
```

#### /src/app/+user/user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: 'user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

#### /src/app/+user/user.component.html

```
<p>
  It should be showing but it isn't!
</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a known issue in the new RC router.

Alternatively you can also do

```ts
export class MyprojAppComponent {
  constructor(router:Router) {}
```

One of these workarounds is necessary to get the router invoked.

Comment: I also had similar issue, the suggested solution didn't work for me too.. any other thing I might missing?

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you provide a Plunker to reproduce? Switching to the new RC router is currently not adviceable anyway. It's likely they'll ship yet another router soon.

Comment: The funny thing is, `@angular/router-deprecated` wasn't working, though will add a plunkr in my night time.. Thanks :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks dude!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I started my application back from scratch, so that made it working(I must have missed something silly before), Thanks :)

Comment: thank you, this solved my issue. And my attribute had to like this:
<a routerLink="/courses">Courses</a>

Answer (score 3):

I struggled few hours with returned empty `[routerLink]`. There was no error on console. I had to add `<base href="/">` on header of index.html. It worked after that.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Well, doing exactly this fixed it for me, so a good comment then ;)

Comment: If I change, base href to something other than `'/'`, it does not work. In my deployment, the app is not deployed on `'/'` but some path like `'/webapp'`

Answer (score 1):

As Gunter said, this is a known bug with the current RC (here's one of several issues on it: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/989). The approach that the angular tutorial and many others are taking right now is to use `@angular/router-deprecated`. Starting from just after `ng new myproj` and `ng g route user`, you'll need to do the following:

1. `npm install --save @angular/router-deprecated`
2. In `src/system-config.ts`, change `@angular/router` to `@angular/router-deprecated` in the `barrels` array.
3. In `src//app/myproj.component.ts`, change:

   1. `Routes` to `RouteConfig` in the `import` line
   2. `'@angular/router'` to `'@angular/router-deprecated'` in the `import` line
   3. `@Routes` to `@RouteConfig` for the decorator
   4. Add the property `name: 'User'` to the `RouteConfig` object for `/user`

Also, note that for links in the pre-RC router you do `<a [routerLink]="['User']">User Info</a>` (i.e. reference the `name` rather than the `path`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew this way, but I was trying/intending to use the new routing system.